# fetchedResultsController returning nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using Core Data as a means to save data in a GeoFencing project. I've got the GeoFencing portion of the app is working as it should. I'm running into a problem saving my `MKMapItem` objects that I'm retrieving.

Long story short, when I do a segue **I return a value for `managedObjectContext`**, BUT **`nil` for `fetchedResultsController`.** I'm stumped as to why.

**Here's my setup**

*Search for items:* Once a user finds something on the map they want to save, they segue from `ResultsTVC` to `AddPointOfInterestVC`.

`AddPointOfInterestVC` unwraps the `MKMapItem` and displays name, address, etc. This part works. Where I'm running into trouble is inserting it in the `managedObjectContext` from the `AddPointOfInterestVC`.

In `prepareForSegue` from `ResultsTVC` to `AddPointOfInterestVC`, I set the `managedObjectContext` and the `fetchedResultsController` so I can click a button in `AddPointOfInterestVC` to add an `MKMapItem` with a note and a category using `insertNewObject`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton*)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addPOISegue"]) {
        AddPOIViewController *destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        // point added here so the button "knows" which index it's referring to
        CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
        NSLog(@"NSIndexPath *indexPath's index is %@", indexPath);
        MKMapItem *item = _mapItems[indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"ResultsTVC item is %@", item);
        destinationVC.item = item;

        // Core Data segue setup

        // Pass the MOC to destinationVC
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        destinationVC.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        // Pass the FRC to destinationVC
        destinationVC.fetchedResultsController = appDelegate.fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

My `AddPointOfInterestVC`

`.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"

// Core Data Properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

`.m` file

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"AddPOIVC item is %@", self.item);
        NSLog(@"AddPOIVC managedObjectContext is %@", self.managedObjectContext);
        NSLog(@"AddPOIVC fetchedResultsController is %@", self.fetchedResultsController);
        }
```

I return a value for `managedObjectContext`, but nil for `fetchedResultsController`. I'm stumped as to why.

Prior to this project, I've used "canned code", so inserting/removing to/from the MOC outside a MasterVC/DetailVC is proving to be a bit trickier for me. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code where `fetchedResultsController` is initialized

Comment: If I could vote myself down, I would. At your suggestion, I looked in my AppDelegate and no FRC, so I instantiated it on the `AddPointOfInterestVC` in `viewDidLoad`. Is `FRC` something that I need to pass around, or is it something I can instantiate on `VC`s "as needed"?

Comment: It's normally something that a view controller creates if it needs one. It's not usually passed around like the managed object context.

Comment: @AdrianB, it depends. But often it used in a single view controller. You may pass MOC to the view controller and let it create FRC as it needed. Sometimes it may be useful to inject FRC into controller from outside (for example if you have a generic view controller that shows same data but with different options like filtering, sorting and current controllers is not responsible for changing this settings - in this case you should provide pre-configured FRC from some other place)

Comment: Awesome! Next Q. My `AddPointOfInterestVC` is for displaying 1 thing and dumping it in the `managedObjectContext` when I click a save `UIButton`. Should I be bringing over my `managedObjectContext` AND my `managedObjectModel` + `persistentStoreCoordinator` to `AddPointOfInterestVC ` so I can create my new `POI`? This is the first time I've monkeyed w/ Core Data outside a standard `Master/Detail` setup.